# Html in php mail function

Tags: php

I have my mail function code as belove.

```
$subject = "Account Expiration";
$headers  =  'MIME-Version: 1.0'.PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'.PHP_EOL; 
$headers .= 'From: '.$from . ''.PHP_EOL ;
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$from .''.PHP_EOL;

$message = "<html><body>";
$message .= "<h1 style='color:#f40;'>Account Expiry</h1>";              
$message .= "<p style='color:#f40;font-size:18px;'>Your Account is get  xpired.You can not able to bid more.For Further Bidding Please Sigunup on Our sight.</p>";
            $message .= '<p><a href ="'.$url.'" style="color:#07c;font-size:16px;">click here for signup</a></p>';              
            $message .= "</body></html>";
```

Emails are sent, but `<a href=""></a>` tag is not working in mail.

Comment: where you set the value of $url variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = "<html>
            <body>
                <h1 style='color:#f40;'>Account Expiry</h1>
                <p style='color:#f40;font-size:18px;'>
                    Your Account is get expired.You can not able to bid more.For Further Bidding Please Sigunup on Our sight.
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a href ='". $url ."' style='color:#07c;font-size:16px;' target='_blank'>click here for signup</a>
                </p>
            </body>
        </html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url="https://www.google.co.in";
$message = '<p><a href ="'.$url.'" style="color:#07c;
font-size:16px;">click here for signup</a></p>';
echo $message ;
```